# Excel, return unique values values from an array, but don't return blank values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Here's my formula:
`=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,UNIQUE(IF(A2=Sheet1!$E:$E,Sheet1!$L:$L,"")))`

Here's my result:
`0, AOI-1, AOI-2`

So far it's working to return unique values in Sheet1!$L:$L; but I don't want it to return a 0 for the blank values in Sheet1!$L:$L.

All rows in Sheet1!$E:$E have values that are not blank, my values to return are sometimes blank, but I don't want to see those returned.

Another way to say it is, if VALUE_IS_TRUE is blank, don't return it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leverage the FILTER function, in which you can specify the value to be returned if blank

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,UNIQUE(FILTER(Sheet1!$L:$L,A2=Sheet1!$E:$E,"")))
```

The parameters for FILTER are

```
=FILTER(array, include, [if blank])
```

So we are returning an array from column L if the value in column E matches A2, and if column L is blank it will return nothing for that value.

Comment: That did it! I tried filter, but it was backwards